# Flex 4: Crossfade transition of two VideoDisplays does not work

Tags: apache-flex, transition, states, videodisplay

I'm trying to do a cross-fade transition in Flex between two states, both containing a VideoDisplay object. The problem is that the default CrossFade effect takes a bitmap snapshot of both states and blends between the two. This means that the movies appear to be frozen for the time of the transition.

Does anybody know of a solution that uses a PixelBender (GPU-accelerated) method of fading between two movies? My other option is to manually re-order the video objects and change the alpha of the top one, but this uses a lot of CPU (in my case ±300%)...

**States:**

**Transition:**

```
<s:transitions>
    <s:Transition >
        <s:CrossFade id="crossfader" target="{this}" duration="{fadeTime}"  />  
    </s:Transition>
</s:transitions>
```

**Objects:**

```
<components1:VideoDisplay 
                    id="movie_attract" 
                    width="640" x="0" height="480" y="0"

                    source="{configuration.movieAttract.source}"

                    includeIn="attract" 

                    />
<components1:VideoDisplay 
                    id="movie_engage" 
                    left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"

                    source="{configuration.movieEngage.source}"
                    includeIn="engage" 

                    />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found that using the Spark Fade (not CrossFade) works (and performs) better for me.

Replacing your CrossFade line with the following should work.

```
<s:Fade id="crossfader" targets="{[ movie_attract, movie_engage ]}" duration="{fadeTime}"  />
```

Disclaimer: I have not tested this with VideoDisplays that are currently playing a video. But even with paused videos, the Fade effect performed much better than CrossFade. Fade was smooth and not jerky, unlike CrossFade. I know this is not strictly answering your question, but you may want to try it out.

Comment: This works, I tested it! The only drawback to this solution is that it used a lot of CPU, especially with large video files.

Comment: Glad I could help. :-) If it has solved your problem, don't forget to mark it as the answer.